# Select element with div and class and data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

How do I select a element using it's element type (Div), a class (spaceEvent) and a data attribute (data-event-id)?

here is an example of a element

```
<div class="spaceEvent" data-event-id=112>
```

and I want to find this element so that I can search for stuff inside it?

my guess would be something like

```
$("div.spaceEvent").find("[event-id=112]")
```

but I'm not sure!

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are almost correct, but you need to combine them in to a single jQuery object. Your use of `find()` means that you're currently looking for a child element of the div instead of looking for a div with all the specified attributes.

Try this instead:

```
$('div.spaceEvent[data-event-id="112"]')
```

Comment: why do I need to put the number (112) inside quotes? its a number not a wiord

Comment: You don't have to in this case, but it's a better convention. The type of the value is not relevant to the selector, but if there is a space in the value you *have* to wrap it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option:

```
$('div.spaceEvent[data-event-id="112"]')
```

Comment: The `.find()` version is wrong. `.find()` only looks for elements inside, not the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `$('div.spaceEvent[data-event-id="112"]');`
- `$('div.spaceEvent').filter('[data-event-id="112"]');`

The `find()` function searches the children, not itself. More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: `.is()` just returns a boolean telling if the element has the data, it doesn't return the element.

Comment: Quotes are only required if the attribute value contains special characters.

Comment: Opps... Didn't know that. Thanks!